# Does for..in loop keeps track of orders of its properties for Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, reduce

I'm a beginner for programming in general, and JavaScript is my first language. While I was studying, I faced with this concern, and I'm not sure if my concern is appropriate.

I thought `for..in` loop does not keep track of orders when we loop through an Object, because, unlike Arrays, Object's properties are not index based.

This leads me to question my work on recreating some of the methods from Underscore.js such as `_.each` and `_.reduce`

Below is my attempts to recreate those methods.

```
var each = function(list, iteratee) {
    if (Array.isArray(list)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            iteratee(list[i], i, list);
        }
    } else if (list.constructor === Object) {
        for (var key in list) {
            iteratee(list[key], key, list);
        }
    }
};

var reduce = function(list, iteratee, memo){  
  var memoUndefined = arguments.length < 3;
  each(list, function(elem, index, list){
    if (memoUndefined) {
      memoUndefined = false;
      memo = elem;
    } else {
        memo = iteratee(memo, elem, index, list);
    }
  });
  return memo;
};
```

They seem to work correctly, such that works on both Array and Object as its `list`, with or without `memo` supplied to it.

However, what makes me wonder is that how does my `each` function keep track of the orders of properties it is iterating over? How would it make sure the orders of the properties being looped is always consistent? It makes sense for Arrays because it's properties are index. But Object's is not. I believe this might have a potential issue when being implemented in a function like my `reduce` above. If what `iteratee` does in the future is just simple addition or subtraction it might be fine, but what about multiplications or division? The orders of values `each` will iterate will be crucial. Is my concern appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ECMAScript ES5 specification specifically says that the order of properties is not guaranteed for a `for/in` loop.  From [section 12.6.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) in the ES5 specification:

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the
>   first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

Though, in most browser implementations of ES5, properties are iterated in the order they were created.

I have read that it has been proposed to document the order of properties for for/in as the order created in the emerging ES6 specification.

I haven't found this specific wording in the ES6 draft, but there is this note about `Object.keys()`:

> If an implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the
>   for-in statement, the same order must be used for the elements of the
>   array returned in step 4.

Keep in mind that even if the order is always a specific way, there are no features for modifying the order.  So, if you really care about order of properties, then it is likely that a `for/in` loop on an object is not really the right way to store/access an ordered set of properties.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now I wonder how popular libraries like Underscore.js or lodash.js implement their collection methods to accomodate Objects. Do they turn it into an Array-like object?

Comment: @KyleC - It's possible to iterate properties of an object without knowing what order the items will come in.  That's what `jQuery.each()` does, for example.  I don't quite understand your comment about underscore or lodash in this regard.  FYI, the source code to underscore and lodash is available to look at.  Why not just go see what they do?

Comment: I looked at the source codes for `reduce` method in underscore and lodash, but they involved foreign methods like `optimizedCb`. I just couldn't follow their code since I'm a very beginner.

Comment: The way to follow code like that is to create a simple test page with a non-minimized version of the libary and then step through the code line by line in the debugger.  This will let you see exactly what it's doing.  If you haven't yet learned how to use the debugger, that's a very worthwhile thing to do and doesn't take that long (particularly if you've used other debuggers).

Comment: Thank you. I will look into how to use debuggers. Do you know what's a good debugger to start with? Is Chrome dev tool kind of a debugger?

Comment: @KyleC - The debugger built into Chrome is very good and is what I use. Others like Firebug, an add-on for Firefox.